# Text not allowed in element ul in this context

Tags: validation

I do not understand this error message from the markup validation service and I have been unable to find an answer. It seems that the Service is pointing to the &nbsp. I want to put a blank line between each of my links. Thank you.

**Text not allowed in element ul in this context**

```
<div id="content">
        <h1>Green Light Data Technologies</h1>
        <h2>Product List</h2>
           <div id="prod-list">
              <ul>
                 <li><a href="patch-cords.html" target="_blank">Patch Cords</a></li>
                 &nbsp;
                 <li><a href="ethernet.html" target="_blank">Ethernet Cards</a></li>
                 &nbsp;
                 <li><a href="bulk-wire.html" target="_blank">Bulk Wire</a></li>
                 &nbsp;
                  <li><a href="rj45.html" target="_blank">RJ45* Connectors</a></li>
                  &nbsp;
   </ul>
</div>
        </div><!--/#content-->
```

Answer (score 0):

While waiting for an answer, I kept looking and this is what I found on:
http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum21/8348.htm

Not a direct quote, add the &nbsp within the li tags. I think the answers came from Tedster and Span in response to a similar question asked by JayCee.

This worked for me.
Kindest Regards